# Import existing docker containers to openshift

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I have about 14 containers most of them are Java apps and I have an nginx container. I do a docker create network and do a build and run under the same network. I then expose my nginx container on 8080, go to a :8080/resources/public/client/web/index.html and I have my application running there.

I have imported these containers to openshift in a single project and I've been successful. But when I open the route to 8080 on the nginx server I get a Welcome to Nginx landing page. When I add the path /resources/public/client/web/index.html it doesnt open anything.

How do I link these containers together within Openshift? I'm looking for a bit of guidance. It's fairly easy to do just with Docker create network.

Comment: Are you building your HTML files into the nginx image, or are you expecting to mount them in from a volume? Can you explain more about what you are doing to deploy the images and expose them via a route? Have you used ``oc rsh`` to get into the container for the nginx deployment and from the shell checked if your files are in the place you expect?

Comment: I am expecting them to mount from volume. My container called resources has the files needed for my java web app.

I have looked into the containers and I notice some files missing in openshift. This shouldnt be the case as I imported the docker images directly after building and running them.

Comment: Running your docker image locally with a local file system mounted as volume, doesn't then result in your files getting copied in to the image. You would need to claim a volume in OpenShift mount it against your application and then copy the files into the volume so persist.

Comment: You might want to go through exercises at https://learn.openshift.com/ and in particular the one about transferring files in and out of containers (and volumes).

Comment: If you are just hosting static files, you might be better off looking at the S2I builder for nginx or Apache httpd. You just need to point it at a repo with your files and it will handle the rest. https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container https://github.com/sclorg/httpd-container The Apache one should already be in the service catalog when you add something to a project from the web console.